# Fabric: current hostname as a variable

Tags: git, fabric

I want to use the name of a remote host in a local fabric command

```
$ fab -H my_servername,my_secondserver do_setup
```

and in the `fabfile.py`

```
from fabric.api import local, lcd, run, sudo, put
def do_setup():
    # ... set up remote repository
    lcd('/local/dev_directory/')
    local('git remote add %{remote_name}s %{remote_user}s@%{remote_ip}s' % ???)
```

Is there any way of getting the current connection details (`my_servername` and `my_secondserver` in turn)?
I've defined the actual ip addresses of `my_servername` in /etc/hosts, and the user is the same as the local user.

Comment: Thanks, thought I had done a thorough search.